# Unique members of two lists

Tags: excel, vba

I use this to see which clients have been added to our client list and which have left, month to month.

It takes two lists, then outputs the unique and common members of the two lists. There may be better ways of doing this, but the logic is simple and easy to follow and it seems to work. e.g.

A
B
*A*
*B*
AB
1
3
1
5
3

2
4
2
6
4

3
5

4
6

```
Option Base 1

Sub UniqueMembersOfTwoLists()

Dim arrOne() As Variant  
Dim arrTwo() As Variant  
Dim AB() As Variant  
ReDim AB(0 To 0) As Variant  
Dim A_Only() As Variant  
ReDim A_Only(0 To 0) As Variant  
Dim OnlyInListB() As Variant  
ReDim OnlyInListB(0 To 0) As Variant

Dim lrOne As Long  
Dim lrTwo As Long

Dim r1 As Range  
Dim r2 As Range  
Dim i As Long  
Dim test As Variant  
Dim g As Boolean

‘Dim ms As String  
‘ if needed  
‘ms = "Put list 1 in column A starting in A1, put list 2 in column B staring B1"  
‘MsgBox ms  

lrOne = Range("A65336").End(xlUp).Row  
lrTwo = Range("B65336").End(xlUp).Row

Set r1 = Range((Cells(1, 1)), (Cells(lrOne, 1)))  
Set r2 = Range((Cells(1, 2)), (Cells(lrTwo, 2)))

arrOne = r1  
arrTwo = r2

‘simple check to see if each member of list B is in List A  
For Each Element In arrTwo  
    test = Element  
    g = contained(arrOne, test)  

    If g = True Then  
        ' means is a member of both lists, add to common members list  
        ReDim Preserve AB(0 To UBound(AB) + 1)  
        AB(UBound(AB)) = test

    Else
        ‘means only in list A, so add to A only  
        ReDim Preserve A_Only(0 To UBound(A_Only) + 1)    
        A_Only(UBound(A_Only)) = test

    End If

Next Element

‘ then repeat the other way round to find only in list B  

For Each w In arrOne  
    test = w  
    g = contained(arrTwo, test)  

    If g = True Then  
        ' means is a member of both lists, already added so do nothing  
    Else  
        ReDim Preserve OnlyInListB(0 To UBound(OnlyInListB) + 1)  
        OnlyInListB(UBound(OnlyInListB)) = test  
    End If  

Next w

' out put to sheet  

For i = 1 To UBound(AB)  
    Cells(i, 5).Value = AB(i)  
Next i  
i = 1  

For i = 1 To UBound(A_Only)  
    Cells(i, 4).Value = A_Only(i)  
Next i  
i = 1  

For i = 1 To UBound(OnlyInListB)  
    Cells(i, 3).Value = OnlyInListB(i)  
Next i  
i = 1  

‘ tidy up

Rows("1:1").Select  
Selection.Insert Shift:=xlDown, CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove  
Range("A1").Select  
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "List A"  
Range("B1").Select  
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "List B"  
Range("C1").Select  
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "Only in List A"  
Range("D1").Select  
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "Only in List B"  
Range("E1").Select  
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "In both A & B"  
Rows("1:1").Select  
Selection.Font.Bold = True      
Cells.Select  
Cells.EntireColumn.AutoFit  

End Sub

Function contained(arr() As Variant, test As Variant)  
Dim i As Long  
Dim a As Variant  
Dim g As Boolean  
g = False  

For i = 1 To UBound(arr)  
    a = arr(i, 1)  
    If a = test Then  
        g = True  
        Exit For  
    Else  
    End If  
Next i  

contained = g  

End Function
```

Is there a more efficient way of achieving the same, possibly using a dictionary?

Comment: Not asked as a question looking for other input.

Comment: I couldn't find this when doing a search and there might be others who need it, so I posted it. I use it for seeing which clients have been added to our client list and those that have left, month to month. Is there a more efficient way of achieving the same? possibly using a dictionary?